# User Profile details are not available in the Search

Tags: search, people-search

We have more than 90K users in our SharePoint 2010 env., however a particular user details are unavailable in the People search though the user profile is active since last 5yrs. Seems that User profile is ignored while Crawling the people content...Not sure, what to check as it works for the remaining all those users...What could be the issue?

**Update:**
Have used the below SQL query to verify the crawl log however it does not have any entry for that specific user alone(though the user profile is still exists in the UPA also verified the UPA & SSA association)

```sql
SELECT top 100 u.crawlid, u.accessurl, u.ContentSourceID, u.LastModifiedTime, 
               u.LastTouchStart, u.DisplayURL, u.errorid, e.errormsg
FROM [CrawlStoreDB_39e84a89127c493c896b9296fdb51f5d].[dbo].[MSSCrawlURL] u
    join [CrawlStoreDB_39e84a89127c493c896b9296fdb51f5d].[dbo].[MSSCrawlErrorList] e
    on u.errorid=e.errorid
where u.DisplayURL like '%userId%' and u.ContentSourceID = 3
```

I do not think, we may need to check the FIM as the user profile is already exist in the UPA...any clue?

Comment: So you're missing one particular detail about any user or missing one user in the search-results?

Comment: missing only one user profile..

Comment: Just making sure I understand you correct: The User Profile is there, but it is not indexed? Eg. you can look at the profile in your My Site hosts Person.aspx page, but if you search for the user in People search he doesnt show up? In that case I would concentrate on the search log for your People content source. Do a *full* crawl. Check for errors, and check if the account in question appears under crawled URLs in log

Comment: exactly, the same is what I have done..have verified the crawl logs of the people content source(used the above sql query and also extracted the crawl logs using PS) however  could not find anything is logged for that specific user alone..moreover the same user profile is searchable in the QA system..

Comment: what QA system is that, and does it use search or API?

Comment: Did you get any fruitful answer, as I am also facing the same problem and also check the log, not error for specific user.

Answer (score 2):

The FIM sync service is by far the most complex service in SP2010.

Some things to check:

Debugging the synchronization service you can use the FIM Client to check for issues in the sync process. The client is usually located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe

Select a full sync and look for the specific user. This can show you why a given user is not included in the sync.

Also check if specific sync filter rules excludes the user. You find sync filters on the sync connection in the context menu.

UPDATE:
Since user profile appears to be synchronized from AD, concentrate on the search log for your People content source. Do a full crawl. Check for errors, and check if the account in question appears under crawled URLs in log.

If you find the item, select it and click "Recrawl this item in the next crawl". It will now be flagged for retry in next crawl.

Answer (score 1):

What diagnostic tests have you tried?

Have you used Search Explorer to directly query the service Application using SQL?
http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/08/15/free-developer-search-tool-for-sharepoint-2010-search-and-fast-search-for-sharepoint.aspx

Can you see the user in there?  Are there any rules in your scope that would prevent the user from being displayed?  Has the user contributed anything in SharePoint Lists? Is this SharePoint Search or FAST search?

Also - review this article to see if it helps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/natebaum/archive/2010/04/13/sharepoint-2010-people-search-missing-content-mystery-solved.aspx

Sorry for all the questions, trying to get a better idea of what could cause this.

Good Luck!!

Comment: Have you tried deleting the User Profile - re-running your sync + re adding meta data + re running full crawl?  I know this isn't an answer, but potentially there is some corruption in the record.  Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, it might help here however it may also re-add this colleagues and triggers the newsfeed...anyway will try..